# Еще вопрос по С бюлдер

Tags: c, c++builder

Мне нужно  написать программу  для вычисления сопротивления при параллельном     соединений  (но в чем проблема  результат 0 выходит хотя это неверно) где не правильно Си бюлдер

```
    {int sopr1, sopr2, sopr3, sopr4, sopr5;
    float result;
    sopr1=StrToInt(Edit1->Text);
    sopr2=StrToInt(Edit2->Text);
    sopr3=StrToInt(Edit3->Text);
    sopr4=StrToInt(Edit4->Text);
    sopr5=StrToInt(Edit5->Text);
    result=((1/sopr1)+(1/sopr2)+(1/sopr3)+(1/sopr4)+(1/sopr5));
    Edit6->Text=FloatToStr(result);
    }
```

Comment: вы не учитесь на своих же ошибках. У вас опять то же самое - вы делите целое число на целое, и в результате получаете тоже целое. замените 1/sopr1 на 1.0/sopr1 (и все остальные тоже)

Comment: извините не подскажите , как вычислить синус любого угла в бюлдере

Answer (score 3):

1) си бюлдера - нет такого, видимо это с++ builder.
2) результат выражение `1/sopr1` будет равен 0 (может конечно есть вариант, когда это не так). Потому что при делении двух целых чисел, результат будет целым. и Ваши результат будет целым! Это базовые вещи. Это нужно выучить в самом начале.

варианта решения два - либо сделать все переменные float, либо делить правильно.

```
result=((1.0/sopr1)+(1.0/sopr2)+(1.0/sopr3)+(1.0/sopr4)+(1.0/sopr5));
```

Но мне кажется, что эта формула не посчитает сопротивление верно.

Comment: @KoVadim @parol складывает проводимости (что есть правильно при параллельном соединении), но вот перевести результирующую проводимость обратно в сопротивление -- забывает.

Comment: извините не подскажите , как вычислить синус  любого угла в  бюлдере

Comment: @parol используйте библиотечную ф-цию для расчета синуса `sin()`

Comment: @alexlz да знаю я. Все таки на пары ходил. 
@gecube а может ему нужен sinf, который работает с float. просто sin работает с double (но это так для чистого си, где не было перегрузки, в плюсах просто sin). Хотя если у него си бюлдер, то я не знаю...